# Equinox Launcher ignores .ini file and vmargs

Tags: java, eclipse, processbuilder, equinox

I want to start eclipse with the equinox launcher from another java program. The problem is that the launcher seems to ignore my .ini file with the settings for the language or the MaxPermSize.

I'm currently using this code:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("java");
    list.add("-jar");
    list.add("path/to/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar");
    list.add("-data");
    list.add(workspaceLocation);
    list.add("-configuration");
    list.add(configurationLocation);
    //doesn't work
    list.add("--launcher.ini");
    list.add("path/to/test.ini");
    //doesn't work as well
    list.add("-vmargs");
    list.add("-XX:MaxPermSize=256m");
    try {
      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(list);
      Process debugProcess = processBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the .ini file:

```
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx3072m
-Dosgi.nl=en_US
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "ignore", does it still launch? What's in that .ini file?

Comment: Yes, eclipse is launching but the parameters for example the language isn't set also the MaxHeapSize etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--launcher.xxxx` options are only used when you use the Eclipse launcher executable to start the RCP (that is the `eclipse` command or similar).

Since you are calling the `java` command directly you will need to specify everything on the command line.

VM arguments for the `java` command should be before the `-jar` option and you don't use `-vmargs`. So:

```
list.add("java");
list.add("-XX:MaxPermSize=256m");
list.add("-jar");
list.add("path/to/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar");
...
```